# How do I create a new line in an .xslt with a line number?

Tags: xslt, newline, line-numbers

I want to create a new line in an .xslt file, with a line number. I know how to create a new line:

```
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
```

However this output simply creates a new line, but not a line number. My desired output would have the line number (for example, 27: ) and then have the text written after, rather than just the text.

edit: the output format is XML. The specific block of code I'm working with looks like so:
`<xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>FINE ACC100 TB (SEC PARA HERE),P-SPS;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>      1:  TC_ONLINE (ON) ;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>      2:  DO[23] = OFF ;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>      3:  CALL VW_USER(Basic10,Perceptron_IMT,Start_Messpunkt,,,Nr=(ROBO ID),,,EIN/AUS=ON) ;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>      4:  WAIT (DI[23]) ;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>      5:  DO[23] = ON ;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>      6:  TC_ONLINE (DI[14] AND DI[24] AND DI[80]) ;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>      ------ </xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>`
This produces the following output:

```
  21:J P[3] 100% FINE ACC100 TB (SEC PARA HERE),P-SPS;
  1:  TC_ONLINE (ON) ;
  2:  DO[23] = OFF ;
  3:  CALL VW_USER(Basic10,Perceptron_IMT,Start_Messpunkt,,,Nr=(ROBO ID),,,EIN/AUS=ON) ;
  4:  WAIT (DI[23]) ;
  5:  DO[23] = ON ;
  6:  TC_ONLINE (DI[14] AND DI[24] AND DI[80]) ;
  ------   ;
```

But I'd want lines 24, 25, 26, etc. before the 1,2,3,...

Comment: It depends on where you are trying to insert line. For example if is is for items in some collection, you can use `position()` to print it for line. You have to have some kind of variable to keep track of line number.

Comment: So which output method respectively format is that, plain text or HTML or some XML format?

Comment: If the format is XML then please provide some context like a minimal input sample, the corresponding output you want to create and your current XSLT.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], including input and the **exact** expected output (as code).

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that looks like good old BASIC!

I think the cleanest approach here would be a 2-pass transformation. First generate the output as XML:

```
<basic>
  <line>TC_ONLINE (ON)</line>
  <line>DO[23] = OFF<line>
  <line>CALL VW_USER(Basic10,Perceptron_IMT,Start_Messpunkt,,,Nr=(ROBO ID),,,EIN/AUS=ON)</line>
  <line>WAIT (DI[23])</line>
</basic>
```

Then serialize to text and add the line numbers in a second pass, which can be done trivially using position() or xsl:number.